# How to make a http-request to send out the same second?

Tags: jmeter

There troubled for a long time , how to make three requests sent along the same second , rather than one by one , I know that this problem can be solved by providing a plurality of thread groups , but I would like to know whether there are other better Methods?

[image]

Comment: The result I want is to send these three requests synchronization

Comment: JMeter doesn't have an ability to run requests in parallel within the same thread; you could develop a custom sampler or custom controller. I saw one implementation online, but someone commented that it doesn't work: https://github.com/franz-see/jmeter-parellarel-request (still could serve as an example)

Comment: Thanks for your advice , I'll try , and I think jmeter official should consider this requirement：）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run 3 requests with one thread.

If you run 3 threads - in that case each of them will execute requests upside down.

If you need it to be done within the bounds of same thread group it could be done like:

- 3 Threads
- 1 HTTP Request Sampler
- [Beanshell PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) to dynamically change URL and params basing on thread number like:

  ```
  switch (ctx.getThreadNum()) {
      case 0:
          sampler.setDomain("example.com");
          sampler.setName("HTTP Request 1");
          break;
      case 1:
          sampler.setDomain("jmeter.apache.org");
          sampler.setName("HTTP Request 2");
          break;
      case 2:
          sampler.setDomain("jmeter-plugins.org");
          sampler.setName("HTTP Request 3");
          break;
  }
  ```

  - [Synchronizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) - to make all 3 requests to fire exactly at the same time

[image: Synchronizing Timer + beanshell]

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) for comprehensive information on using Java and JMeter API to overcome JMeter limitations when designing your load test

Comment: Thank you , now I feel that a plurality of thread groups is the easiest method , but requires more jvm support , in addition would like to ask if my computer is 2.2G my available memory allocated to 2G memory jmeter (jvm) , for example : set HEAP = -Xms2000m -Xmx2000m, then I can establish how much the thread group is the most reasonable ? looking forward to your reply

Comment: My idea is a thread group match a request, for example :
threadGroup1
   -httprequest1
threadGroup2
   -httprequest2
......
If there are many such requests would need a lot of thread group , but the memory (jvm) whether it is able to keep up , or how many threads can support group

Comment: No matter how many thread groups you create, overhead is minimal. Threads - this is what matters. Also check out [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) for some JMeter tuning tips and tweaks

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

[image]You can put the HTTP Request Sample in a Loop Controller and set the loop to your desired number of times. This way you can send multiple request of the same data, while your session still remains the same.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion , but did not solve the problem , and now I use a loop controller , but the start time three requests to synchronize or not , I wanted a synchronous request .

Comment: if you wish for all request to run at the same time, the only option you have is to increase thread users and set the ramp-up time to 1 second

Comment: Yes, I also consider the use of this method, but if there are many httprequest I need to set up multiple thread users this is not the consumption of jmeter big before ? Also do not know how many threads in the end groups can be set , is not based on jvm

Comment: The number of threads you can set depends on your machine resources, assuming that your jmeter test is simple and doesn't contain much preprocessors and postprocessors you can set your thread users to a high value